# ¿EN ESTA LINEA DE CODIGO, LO QUE ESTA RESALTADO EN NEGRITA QUE ME INDICAN ESAS INSTRUCCIONES?

Tags: java

EN ESTA LINEA DE CODIGO QUE QUIERE DECIR LAS INSTRUCCIONES "**ItemEvent e**" Y "**e.getStateChange() == 1**"?

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    if (e.getStateChange() == 1) {
                        msg.setText("Jessica is selected");
                    } else {
                        msg.setText("Jessica is unselected");
                    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esto es simplemente una funcion que recibe como parametro un objeto del tipo ItemEvent, y despues lo usa adentro. esa es tu duda?

Comment: Básicamente, estas *instrucciones* te están indicando que antes de empezar copiando código encontrado en internet debes aprender las bases del lenguaje. Eso es lo que te están indicando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemEvent e` es el objeto de la funcion, un objeto de tipo `ItemEvent` cuyo nombre sera e.

`e.getStateChange() == 1` significa que estas aplicando el metodo `getStateChange()` sobre tu objeto e, el ==1 es para la comparacion de la condicional, esta diciendo que si el valor retornado es igual a 1 ejecute la accion de abajo, es decir `msg.setText("Jessica is selected");`

Te recomiendo leer la documentación de Java donde viene mas explicado https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getStateChange()

Comment: y getStateChange() que es lo que significa?

Comment: Es un metodo ya predefinido en Java que retorna el estado de tu objeto (seleccionado o no seleccionado), te recomiendo leer la documentacion de Java donde viene mas explicado.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getStateChange()

Comment: Te recomiendo agregar este comentario a la respuesta, ya que la enriquece.